# How code changes to a website in production are done without its users noticing it?

Tags: php, git, web-hosting

Assume there is a website in production i.e hosted in some web hosting company server and publicly accessible via web.

Now the developer wants to do some code changes. Is the following procedure is what being taken in real web companies?

1. Developer does the changes in its own local Git repo.
2. Code review.
3. Developer push the code to the remote Git repo.
4. Developer goes to the web server, and does "git fetch->rebase" to get the latest updates.

Then, once user refreshes the page, the changes will be reflected on its browser.

Is the above procedure correct (I know it might be over simplified, but I just want to know if this the general flow)?

Comment: "the webserver"... any large site doesn't have just **ONE** webserver... they can push the code to an offline server, then swap out that server with an out-of-date one... or patch an entire farm of servers, then swap all requests to the new farm and take the outdated farm offline.

Comment: Smaller sites can use Git (and I use it too) but Git was never really designed for code deployment. It is better to have a build process that sets up your site in various ways - that might include a Git operation, but you might also have Composer and Bower calls, a migration from your ORM, etc.

Comment: Have a [read of this](https://leftnode.org/posts/expert-php-deployments.html), it's more thorough than can really be answered here.

Comment: Halfer, so you recommend the book: Expert PHP Deployments. Thanks :-) http://www.amazon.com/Expert-PHP-Deployments-Vic-Cherubini-ebook/dp/B00HDHUQX4/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1437072681&sr=1-1&keywords=php+deployment

Comment: I think it is good advice from a knowledgeable author, and yes if you like it, it is a nice gesture to purchase it. I did not know it was available through Amazon.

Comment: In relation to one of your questions, you do not need to do a `git pull rebase` on a deployment machine. Rebasing is only necessary if the local repo might have commits that are not in your development branch. However, since you should not be developing on the local machine, this will not happen - if there is any merging to be done you should absolutely avoid doing this on live. Do it in master on your local machine, resolve any conflicts there, and then `git pull` in staging/live.

Comment: `Wait until off-peak -> deploy -> quick test -> if(ok) -> deep test -> if(ok) -> done. If(any test fail) -> rollback-> stop`. That is the basic flow. When your website is bigger like a real time website with millions of users, problem is not only about technology. It's about how we get a good processes.

Comment: 0 downtime requires multiple production instances

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this would be to use a [`git hook`](https://git-scm.com/book/it/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks). For instance you could do the following:

On your production server you create a clone of your repository placing it under `/var/git/<repository>`, then rename or copy `/var/git/<repositiory>/hooks/post-update.sample` to `/var/git/<repository>/hooks/post-update`. Then edit `/var/git/<repository>/hooks/post-update`, changing it into something like:

```
 !/bin/sh  
 # move into location of your production folder  
 cd /var/www/<repository> || exit  
 unset GIT_DIR  
 # pull the /var/git/<repository> into production  
 git pull hub master`
```

Make sure the `/var/git/<repository>/hooks/post-update` is exectable running:

```
 chmod +x /var/git/<repository>/hooks/post-update
```

Then you move into the web root for your production and clone the repository.

```
 cd /var/www/<repository>/
 git clone /var/git/<repository>
 cd <repository>
 git remote rename origin hub
```

Finally in your local environment you would add a remote:

```
 git remote add production <user>@<server>:/var/git/<repository>
```

And then you can push your local changes to the production servers repository, which in turn will trigger the `post-update` hook, which will checkout the master to the production folder. Notice that you also need to push your changes to the actual master repository:

```
 git push staging master
```

You should notice that this does **not** handle any database migration. To handle this I would use a `CI` like [`Jenkins`](https://jenkins-ci.org/) or similar.

Answer (score 1):

Do a master branch for production, and each upload will be a merge to this master branch and push, on prod server do a pull. Easy piece.

Comment: How would you handle database migrations or Composer updates in this workflow?

Comment: I am newbie to web development. I have never handled db migration. Based on your input, by saying "db migration", you mean switch from one db to a completely another db (like from mysql to sqlite) for example?

Comment: mainly yes, adding this master branch only for the prod env (even you could have a master branch on you dev machine, but do no mess this branch, respect as sacred and you will be allways safe to do a pull on master branch on prod machines). And also i prefer not do a rebase, is not necesary and sometimes dangerous if you work with someone else

Comment: @Qwerty: _migrations_ are a defined process to change the database from one version to another; [see here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.migration) for how Yii does it. It's supported by major ORMS like Propel and Doctrine, and the database component of many frameworks, like Laravel, also have one too. Migrations are developed and perfected in a local environment, and then can be run on any copy of the same app, either "up" (usual) or "down" (rollback if there's a problem).